# TPL Dataflow: Cancellations

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

In a long list of [IDataflowBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock?view=netcore-2.2)'s in the .Net library, if I want to limit the execution of the entire collection of blocks to a TimeSpan (say, 5 seconds), does it suffice if I pass a single [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8) in the last block's constructor (through [DataflowBlockOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions?view=netcore-2.2) of course) ?

I think the question stands on its own, but for a bit of context, an example:

```
var token = new CancellationToken(5000);
var options = new DataflowBlockOptions{ CancellationToken = token };

// DataflowBlockOptions not used although possible through overloading
var block1 = new Bufferblock<int>(/*options*/);

// DataflowBlockOptions not used although possible through overloading
var block2 = new TransformBlock<int,int>(i => i + 1/*, options*/);

// Options used here to limit total time to 5 seconds.
var block3 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => Console.WriteLine(i), options);

block1.LinkTo(block2);
block2.LinkTo(block3);

block1.Post(...)

await block3.Completion;
```

Another way to ask the question: Is there a any benefit here to uncomment the `/* options */` in the above snip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *want* all your Dataflow blocks to fault, then you should pass `CancellationToken` as an option to each. Alternatively, you could pass it as an option to the first one, and propagate your completion in `LinkTo`. I don't normally cancel my meshes, but that's my preferred approach to shutting down pipeline-style meshes in general: link with completion and then just complete the first one.

If you don't, then you'll end up with two live blocks connected to a completed block, so any items added to the mesh will flow through and end up in an output buffer.

Comment: Thanks. From the expert himself, much appreciated.